# How to loop through struct objects?

Tags: c++, for-loop, struct

I am writing a program that uses the elements of a struct and compares them.

```
    void main()
{   struct data
        { string name;   float dep_score;
        };
      data a;//definining elements of my struct
      data b;
      data c;
      data d;
      data e;
      data f;

     a.name="australia";
     a.dep_score=5.8;
     b.name="canada";
     b.dep_score=7.9;
     c.name="United Kingdom";
     c.dep_score=6.6;
     d.name="United States";
     d.dep_score=10;
     e.name="japan";
     e.dep_score=3.6;
     f.name="france";
     f.dep_score=8.5;// values of the elements
    char i=a;
    char g;
    for (i=a;i<g;i++)//what I want to do..compare the scores of two struct objects 

        { if((i.dep_score+[i+1].dep_score) <=15)
            { cout<< i.name, (i+1).name;

                }

          }
    getch();
}
```

The problem is that I get an error in the 'for' loop. 
1. çhar á'cannot be defined and 'data' cannot be converted to 'çhar'
2. Cannot compare struct elements with <=

Tried resolving it using numbers. What can I use to resolve this error?

Comment: `void main` is not legal C++. Use `int main`.

Comment: Your main problem here is that you have 6 discrete variables that you're treating identically.  C++ is going to fight you on this.  How about you simply use an array, like a real programmer.  :P

Comment: You should take it easy... read an introductory book and if the question remains then come back.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
data a[10];

a[0].name = "x";
a[0].dep_score = 1.0;
....

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   if (a[i].dep_score < a[i+1].dep_score) ....
```

Likely you'll also need to fix more things.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem. It's compiling successfully now!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how it can be done in a c++ way using containers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    struct Data
    {
        std::string name;
        float score;
    };
    typedef std::vector<Data> CountryScores;
    CountryScores scores = { { "australia", 5.8f },
                             {"canada", 7.9f },
                             { "united kingdom", 6.6f },
                             { "united states", 10.0f },
                             { "japan", 3.6f },
                             { "france", 8.5f }
                           };
    if (! scores.empty()) //std::prev(scores.end()) is invalid for empty containers
    {
        for (auto it = scores.begin(); it != std::prev(scores.end()); ++it)
        {
            if (it->score + std::next(it)->score <= 15.f)
            {
                std::cout << "countries " << it->name << " and " << std::next(it)->name << " have low combined scores" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry,I dunno containers, so this is complex for me.

Comment: No problem, but if you want to get things done in C++, better have a look at the provided containers: vector, deque, map,... because I don't see where my code is more complex than the other code.